Excel 2016 gets stuck on opening at 100%
Using excel 2016 (PC) if I double click on an xlsx document it will try to load but get's stuck at 100%. If I open excel from the start menu it will prompt me about the mentioned document (update linked information).
I tried to start excel in safe mode but it doesn't opens up.
This happens on files contained in google drive.
Any ideas what could it be?

Are these files that won’t open configured to always be local on your system or are you opening the file due to them being in the cloud, if you make a copy and save them outside of your Google Drive folder does the file open? Instead of commenting you can [edit] your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please go to File > Options > Trust Center, Trust Center Settings > External Content, under the Security Settings for External Content section, check which option do you select.
